# css : li hover doesn't work in internet explorer 6

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, hover

here is the code : http://jsfiddle.net/yuliantoadi/hMr7h/

if you try to hover the 'test 2' link, the dropdown menu will appear. the problem in IE 6, any idea how to make this dropdown menu work in IE 6?

Comment: This has been asked to death over many years. I'm sure the solution is lying around somewhere...

Comment: I used the HTC file based solution for IE.. Check this link: [http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/csshover.html](http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/csshover.html)

Comment: It's not a bug - it's a feature! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IE 6, `:hover` only works on `a` tags for CSS. If you want hover effects for IE 6, they'll have to be done in Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

you could use some JS to work around.

jquery sample:

```
$(function(){
    $('.link ul li').hover(
        function(){
          $(this).addClass('hover');  
        },function(){
            $(this).removeClass('hover');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hMr7h/1/

Answer (score 0):

That's because IE 6 (and 7, if my memory serves) doesn't support the `:hover` pseudo-class on anything but a link.

You can, however, emulate the behavior with a bit of JavaScript (not using jQuery, unlike choise's answer):

```
var element = document.getElementById('someid'); // I'm leaving this part up to you.
element.onmouseover = function (e) {
    element.className += ' hover';
};
element.onmouseout = function (e) {
    elemen.className.replace(' hover','');
};
```

Comment: IE 7 supports it, "Enable :hover on all elements not just on <a>" see: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2006/08/22/712830.aspx